# Cross reference multiple geodatabases in R to provide summary statistics

Tags: r, spatial

I have a number of different geodatabases in ArcGIS pro. For example:

```
Geodatabase_1 - Broad habitats in the UK
Geodatabase_2 - Survey sites by grid reference (i.e. TF2803). there are 100 survey sites.
Geodatabase_3 - Soil type
```

In R, I want to run some code which will tell me which Soil types and which broad habitats my survey sites sit on.

I can import the geodatabases into R using `sf` as outline here
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/184013/read-a-table-from-an-esri-file-geodatabase-gdb-using-r

But I don't know how to effectively cross reference the layers within R to provide the answer to my above question.

Comment: I think you could use st_join() to get the addtibutes of gdb 1 and 3 for each site in gdb 2.  If your sites are polygons will need to make a decision on how to deal with sites that span boudnaries, in tha case might work better to use st_intersection